React routing not working after deploying on firebase
I have tried 2 routing methods and both of them are working on localhost but after deploying it on firebase hosting it is giving an error page not found. The 2 methods that I have tried are
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<LayoutComponent />} />
    <Route path="/about" element={<About />} /> 
  </Routes> 
</BrowserRouter>

and the other method that I have tried is
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <LayoutComponent />,
  },
  {
    path:'/about',  
    element:<About /> 
  }
]);

LayoutComponent route is working but whenever I try to append a call about component it gives errors.
"url.com/about" is giving an error page not found.
I tried different types of routing but I am confused about what I am doing wrong. I also googled a lot but was not able to figure out what was wrong.

This isn't a problem you can solve on the client side, the server/hosting service should be configured to return the root index.html file for all page requests into the app, and then once the app is correctly served to the client can the React application load & mount and React-Router can synchronize the UI to the current URL path.
Update your firebase.json file to add a rewrite rule to serve the index.html file for files/directories that don't exist.
See Configuring Rewrites for details.
Basic Example:
{
  "hosting": {
    ...

    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],

    ...
  }
}


about route and components exits .why its not routing to about components after deploying @DrewReese

@varunwadhwa Have you configured firebase hosting per the documentation I linked? That's the first step, you have to get your app properly served to the client.

I have configured according to firebase configuration @DrewReese but it still not working

@varunwadhwa Like I said, this isn't anything you can fix with client-side code. Can you edit your post to share your configuration and any other server-side/hosting details you think might be relevant, so we can see where and how you are deploying and serving/hosting the app?
